# Timestamp in where clause

Tags: timestamp, teradata, where-clause

In my Teradata Query I want to do something like this. But its not working-

```
Select *

Where SCAN_TIME > 01/01/2015 13:11:00
```

My SCAN_TIME column is a TIMESTAMP(0) field with data as shown above. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You currently calculate *1 divided by 1 divided by 2105* and get a syntax error complaining about the following `13` :-)

There's only one recommended way to write a TIMESTAMP, using a Standard SQL literal, the keyword `TIMESTAMP'` followed by a string with `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'` format:

```
Where SCAN_TIME > TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 13:11:00'
```

Similar literals exist for date & time:

```
DATE '2015-01-01'
TIME '13:11:00'
```